# How to form a subquery when I have to test multiple tables?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have to perform a delete in my program where I have to test if data is used for other machines. If yes, it shouldn't be deleted, and if no, it can be deleted.

Here are my tables with some test data:

**Machines**
*Id, Name*
1, Machine1
2, Machine2

**Aggregate**
*Id, TypeId,MachineId*
1, 1, 1
1, 1, 2

**AggregateTypes**
*Id, Name*
1, Printer
2, Dryer

**Location**
*Id, AggregateTypeId, Name*
1, 1, POS1
2, 1, POS2
3, 1, POS3
4, 2, POS1
5, 2, POS2
6, 2, POS3

First:

I delete the connection between machine and aggregate in the table Aggregate

```
DELETE FROM Aggregate WHERE Machines.Id = 1
```

Second, I delete the machine

```
DELETE FROM Machines WHERE Machines.Id = 1
```

Until this point it works fine, but now I have to delete all AggregateTypes which have now no connected Machine. Before I can delete the AggregateTypes I have to delete all Locations where the AggregateTypeId = AggregateTypes.Id.

For this I wrote this SQL:

```
DELETE FROM Location WHERE Location.AggregateTypeId =   
(SELECT AggregateTypes.Id FROM AggregateTypes, Aggregate WHERE NOT EXISTS   
(SELECT AggregateTypes.Id FROM Aggregate, AggregateTypes WHERE AggregateTypes.Id = Aggregate.TypeId));
```

It deletes not even one row and I don't know why. I'm new to SQL and want to understand what I did wrong and how I should solve such a problem.

Thanks to **dd619** for his answer.

For everyone who had an equal problem here is my final SQL which works:

```
DELETE FROM Location WHERE Location.AggregateTypeId IN   
(SELECT AggregateTypes.Id FROM AggregateTypes WHERE NOT EXISTS   
(SELECT Aggregate.Id FROM Aggregate WHERE Aggregate.TypeId = AggregateTypes.Id))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [in](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/in.php) operator in where clause of your delete query.

So the query will look like this:

```
DELETE FROM Location WHERE Location.AggregateTypeId IN  
(SELECT AggregateTypes.Id FROM AggregateTypes, Aggregate WHERE NOT EXISTS   
(SELECT AggregateTypes.Id FROM Aggregate, AggregateTypes WHERE AggregateTypes.Id = Aggregate.TypeId));
```

The select query in where clause may return more than one record and hence the condition is failing.Using `in` operator is the correct way to check if your `AggregateTypeId` is present in returned result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the connection between the Machine and Aggregate you could simply do:

```
DELETE FROM aggregate WHERE MachineId = 1;
```

The way I see it you were trying to access a column which does not belong to the Aggregates table.